# Make select helper selects from a set of options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-helpers

I want to be able to select a city from an existing array of cities.

I have stored the cities in an array in the ControllerName controller as a global variable

`$cities = ["city1"...."city20"]`

and I want to be able to access them via : `<%= p.select(:city, $cities{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}) %>`

but then I receive the error message `undefined method name for 'city1'`.

**How can I select from that existing array?
Should I make some controller for cities?**

***Update #1***

I came to make this code

```
$cities=['city1',...'city20']

@city = Array.new
i = $cities.size 

i.times do |x|
  @city[x] = City.new
  @city << $cities[x]
end
```

and instead of `undefined method`name' for "City1":String`I got`undefined method `name' for "City20":String`

PS : **the table of cities has a column named 'name', so the problem isn't particularly there**

**Update #2 : *Issue Solved***

After reading a bit in this Rails Documentation I was able to make a little improvement on my code and I actually could **solve** the issue.

In my form , I have edited the code to that :

`<%= p.select(:city, options_for_select( @cities_array ) )%>`

And in my ControllerName Controller , I have put this :

```
$cities.length.times do |x|
@city = City.new({:name => $cities[x]})
@city.save
  end


@cities_array = City.all.map { |city| [city.name, city.id] }
```

And that was all to it.

If you have any alternative solution , be it simpler or more complex, please share it as an answer.

Comment: If `City` is a model then is better that you add your cities as seeds. Right now your code will add into db all your cities each time you call your action.

Comment: That's right, I was struggling **again** to find a way to set them once and for all. How can I put them as **seeds**

Comment: BTW: The easiest solution (I think): `p.select :city, City.pluck(:name, :id)`

Comment: in `db/seeds.rb`, add your create cities logic there, then in console run `rake db:seed`

Comment: I am a newbie to RoR And Ruby itself, so please provide me some pretty mode detailed guidance, it'll be better if you post it as an answer.

Comment: I will try to elaborate an detailed answer

Comment: I'll be waiting, anyway, I made the logic in seed and made the `rake` task and it works like charm now, in addition to the replacement with `p.select :city, City,pluck(:name, :id)` even though that city has only one attribute so either `map` or `pluck` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options to insert data into your database.

The first one. Add this on a migration:

`rails generate migration add_cities_rows`

inside your migration you can add something like:

```
cities = ['city1', 'city2', 'city3']
cities.each {|city| City.create(name: city)}
```

then you can run: `rake db:migrate`

You can add the same logic in `db/seeds.rb` file so if you want to regenerate your database running `rake db:setup` it will do the magic.

In your `view`(where you are using the **select helper** you can use the following sintaxis to fill the select:

`<%= p.select :city, City.pluck(:name, :id) %>`

So in your controller yo don't needto add any logic

Comment: Imagine there is something I want to add to my database each time, practically each time I call `rake db:seed` the data will be re-written in my database, how to avoid that?

Comment: When you want to add new data just add this a migration "seed stuff" is used when you want to refill/regenerate your database

Comment: I added the logic to `self.up` function in `migration` and I ran `rake db:migrate` but it does not put data into my db. What's happening?

Comment: Something in the log?

Comment: It's the same logic I had put in seed.rb and it had been working.. dunno.

Comment: when you run `rake db:migrate` it shows some info in the log or the console?

Comment: Nope, it waits for about 4 seconds and it returns to the line waiting for other instructions. No message whatsoever.

Comment: It looks lke you are editing an old migration iy you want to rerun then first you should do a rollback or create a new migration

Answer (score 0):

This error is because **'city1'** is a string and you are calling **name** method on a String object which isn't defined.

Probably you may have a **City Model** defined and must be having a **database column **name** within. So name method will be defined for a **City object**

Here, **$cities** is an array of strings which should be an array of **City Objects** instead.

**Yes**, make a controller for Cities and collect city objects array from these array of strings and pass on that to view

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code I should write to make an array of **City Objects** ? 

I came to make this `@city = City.new 
$cities.length.times do |x|
  @city[x] =$cities[x]
            end`

But it does not seem to do the trick.